# Access to Chrome extension elements from frontend

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, frontend

Can I interact with elements of the specific Chrome Extension (e.g. click on a button of the extension) in JS script of my frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension shows a button when clicked on, you get to your profile (Activity tab).
To use this extension you have to be on this site (StackOverflow) but not when you are in Activity tab (otherwise you'll not see the effect).

**Your steps** (more [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd4nr.png)):

- save all files
- go to `chrome://extensions`
- switch browser to **Developer mode**
- click **LOAD UNPACKED**

[image]

> manifest.json

```
{  
    "manifest_version": 2,  

    "name": "Click",  
    "description": "Simple extension",  
    "version": "1.0.0",    
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],  

    "browser_action": {  
        "default_icon": "icon48.png",  
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    }
}
```

> popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>Title</title></head>  
<body>  
    <button id="btn-click">Go to profile</button>  
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

> popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}

document.getElementById('btn-click').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

> content_script.js

```
function clickProfileLink() {
    var stackOverflowProfile = document.getElementsByClassName("my-profile")[0];

    stackOverflowProfile.click();
}

clickProfileLink();
```

**Helpful links**

- [Examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sample) from Google
- Good [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) for beginners

Comment: Artem, thanks for the response. But the question is (more specifically): Can I by clicking on the button on my page invoke an action in the extension (e.g. extension's button click)?

Comment: @VitalyKan Usually, if you like the answer, then you mark it as true

Comment: @VitalyKan got you. Wait a minute

Comment: @AnastasiaAntontseva Unfortunately, I didn't get an answer

Comment: @VitalyKan try new code. I've updated it. Now this is a more illustrative example